# how to apply a function that uses multiple columns as input in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a function `relative_humidity(temperature, humidity_index)` which takes two variables.

I also have a DataFrame with one column being temperature and the other humidity_index, and I am trying to use this function to create a new humidity column which is calculated using these rows.

I have tried using the `df.apply()` function but it hasn't worked for me since I am trying to use more than one column. I have also tried looping through every row and applying the function to each row, but this appears too slow. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: my function looks like this:

```
def relative_humidity_calculator(T, HI):
    a = c_6 + c_8*T + c_9*T**2
    b = c_3 + c_4*T + c_7*T**2
    c = c_1 + c_2*T + c_5*T**2 -HI
    solutions = []
    #adding both solutions of quadratic to list
    if b**2-4*a*c>=0:
        solutions.append((-b+np.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a))
        solutions.append((-b-np.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a))
        #solution is the correct one if it is between 0 and 100
        if solutions[0]>0 and solutions[0]<100:
            return solutions[0]
        else: 
            return solutions[1]
    else:
        return print('imaginary roots', T, HI, a, b, c)
```

Comment: while you can, in general, do: `df.apply(lambda row: relative_humidity(row['temp'], row['humidity_index']), axis=1)`. You should consider vectorize the `relative_humidity` function so you can do `relative_humidity(df['temp], df['humidity_index'])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the response. I understand the basic idea but I'm struggling to actually do this practically. How may I go about this if my `relative_humidity` function is as follows?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I was just about to do that.

Comment: Are the `c_xx` given constants?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, they are specified in the code previously. Only T and HI are variables which I want to take out of df['temp'] and df['heat_index'] respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, you can do this without comprising the function:

```
# sample data:
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9 = range(9)

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(10,2)), columns=['T','HI'])

# shorthand for Temp and Humidity-Index
T = df['T']
HI = df['HI'] 

# series arithmetic operations are allowed 
a = c6 + c8*T + c9*T**2
b = c3 + c4*T + c7*T**2
c = c1 + c2*T + c5*T**2 - HI

# discriminant too
deltas = b**2-4*a*c 
delta_roots = np.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c, where=deltas>0)

# two solutions of quadratic
s0 = (- b + delta_roots)/(2*a)
s1 = (- b - delta_roots)/(2*a)

df['rel_hum'] = np.select(((s0>0) & (s0<100), # condition on first solution
                            deltas>=0),       # quadratic has solutions 
                          (s0, s1), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    T  HI   rel_hum
0  37  12       NaN
1  72   9  0.129917
2  75   5  0.028714
3  79  64 -0.629721
4  16   1       NaN
5  76  71 -0.742304
6   6  25       NaN
7  50  20       NaN
8  18  84       NaN
9  11  28       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and very nicely written. I'm trying to understand this np.select function since it seems like some values smaller than 0 and some greater than 100 are getting through. Can I specify that if s0 doesn't follow both conditions, to check if s1 does? and otherwise input np,nan?

Comment: Yes, basically `np.select((cond1, cond2,...), (value1, value2), default)` is a vectorized version of `for i in range(...): if cond1[i]: ret[i] = value1[i] elif cond2[i]: ret[i] = value2[i] else: ret[i] = default`. You can replace `deltas >=0` with the condition for `s1` and get what you ask for.